# binarySearch errors in Java

Tags: java

I have a BankAccount class that models bank account information and a main method that is supposed to create an array list of BankAccount objects from user input and then write that info to a text file.

Here's my BankAccount class:

```
package BankAccount;

public class BankAccount implements Comparable<BankAccount> {

String accountNumber;
String firstName, lastName;
char middleInitial;
double balance;
public static double OVERDRAFT_FEE = 26.00;

public BankAccount(String acno, String fName, char midInit, String lName, double initBal){
    acno = accountNumber;
    fName = firstName;
    midInit = middleInitial;
    lName = lastName;
    initBal = balance;                
}

public String getAccountNumber(){
    return accountNumber;
}

public String getFirstName(){
    return firstName;
}

public char getMiddleInitial(){
    return middleInitial;
}

public String getLastName(){
    return lastName;
}

public double getBalance(){
    return balance;
}

public void deposit(double amount){
    if (amount > 0)
        balance = balance + amount;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("deposit(double amount): Amount cannot be less than 0.");
}

public void withdraw(double amount){
    if (balance >= amount && amount > 0)
            balance = balance - amount;
    else if(balance < amount && amount > 0)
        balance = balance - amount - OVERDRAFT_FEE;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("withdraw(double amount): Amount cannot be less than 0.");
}

@Override
public int compareTo(BankAccount another){
    if (Integer.parseInt(this.getAccountNumber()) > Integer.parseInt(another.getAccountNumber()))
        return 1;
    else if(Integer.parseInt(this.getAccountNumber()) < Integer.parseInt(another.getAccountNumber()))
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}
}
```

My main method looks like this:

```
public class GeauxBank 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();
    Scanner keyb = new Scanner(System.in);
    // write code to read data from acinfo.dbf. Be sure to handle
    // FileNotFoundException in a try-catch statement. You don't
    // need to do anything in the catch block.
    int option;
    String acno;
    String fName;
    char midInit;
    String lName;
    double initBal=0,amount;
    int pos;
    do 
    {
        menu();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Select an option->");
        option = keyb.nextInt();
        System.out.println();
        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:
                System.out.print("Enter a 10-character long account number->");
                acno = keyb.next();
                System.out.print("Customer's first name ->");
                fName = keyb.next();
                System.out.print("Customer's middle initial ->");
                midInit = keyb.next().charAt(0);
                System.out.print("Customer's last name ->");
                lName = keyb.next();
                System.out.print("Initial Deposit ->");
                initBal = keyb.nextDouble();  
                Collections.sort(accounts);                    
                pos = binarySearch(accounts,acno);
                if (pos < 0)
                {
                   try
                   {
                       accounts.add(new BankAccount(acno,fName,midInit,lName,initBal));
                       Collections.sort(accounts);
                   }
                   catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
                   {
                       System.out.println(e); 
                   }
                }
                else
                    System.out.println(acno+" has already being asssigned another customer");                    
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Enter the 10-character long account number of the account you wish to close->");
                acno = keyb.next();
                pos = binarySearch(accounts, acno);
                accounts.remove(pos);
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Enter the 10-character long account number->");
                acno = keyb.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to deposit->");
                amount = keyb.nextDouble();
                pos = binarySearch(accounts, acno);
                accounts.get(pos).deposit(amount);
                break;
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Enter the 10-character long account number->");
                acno = keyb.next();
                System.out.println("Enter the amount you wish to withdraw->");
                amount = keyb.nextDouble();
                accounts.get(binarySearch(accounts, acno)).withdraw(amount);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Enter the 10-character long account number->");      
                acno = keyb.next();
                accounts.get(binarySearch(accounts, acno)).getBalance();
                break;
            case 6:
                int i;
                int length = accounts.size();
                for(i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    System.out.print(accounts.get(i).getFirstName()+" ");
                    System.out.print(accounts.get(i).getMiddleInitial()+" ");
                    System.out.println(accounts.get(i).getLastName());
                }
                break;
            case 0:
                break;
            default:
               System.out.println("Invalid menu option");                    
        }                                                                  
    }while (option != 0);

    try{
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("acinfo.dbf");
        int i;
        int length = accounts.size();
        for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
            writer.write(accounts.get(i)+"");
        }
        writer.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException f) {
        System.out.println("The file acinfo.dbf does not exist.");
    }

}

/**
 * displays a text-based menu interface for this application
 */
public static void menu()
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("G E A U X    B A N K   L O U I S I A N A   L T D.");
    System.out.println("=================================================");
    System.out.println("[1]...............................open an account");
    System.out.println("[2]..............................close an account");
    System.out.println("[3].......................................deposit");
    System.out.println("[4]....................................withdrawal");
    System.out.println("[5]...............................balance inquiry");
    System.out.println("[6].............................customers listing");
    System.out.println("[0]..........................................exit");
    System.out.println("=================================================");
}

/**
 * searches an array list of BankAccount objects for a matching
 * account number using the Binary Search algorithm.
 * @param accounts an array list of BankAccount objects
 * @param acno a string
 * @return the index of the BankAccount object in the array list or
 * with the account number that is the same as acno if such a BankAccount
 * object can be found in the accounts array list; otherwise, the negative 
 * of the position the BankAccount object whose account number would 
 * have matched acno had it been found.
 */
public static int binarySearch(ArrayList<BankAccount> accounts, String acno)
{
   int i;
   int low,mid=0,high;
   low = 0;
   high = accounts.size()-1;
   while (low <= high)
   {
       mid = (low+high)/2;
       if (acno.compareTo(accounts.get(mid).getAccountNumber())==0)
           return mid;
       else if (acno.compareTo(accounts.get(mid).getAccountNumber())< 0)
           high = mid-1;
       else
           low = mid+1;
   }
   return -1-mid;
}   
}
```

I'm having problems with the binarySearch method. I can create one bank account just fine but when I try to create a second one, I get this message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.String.compareTo(String.java:1167)
    at geauxbank.GeauxBank.binarySearch(GeauxBank.java:172)
    at geauxbank.GeauxBank.main(GeauxBank.java:57)
Java Result: 1
```

It also gives me a similar message any time I try to use any other case in the switch statement that uses the binarySearch method. I don't know why this is. Also, when I try to write the information to a text file, I get this in the text file: BankAccount.BankAccount@1b67f74
or this: null null
I really don't know what is causing these problems. Any insight and clarity would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assignments are the wrong way around.

This takes the parameter and overwrites it with the fields which is `null`. The fields is left as null and you get an NPE when you attempt to dereference it.

```
acno = accountNumber;
```

try

```
accountNumber = acno;
```

I suggest you make fields `final` (unless you need to be able to change them) and you won't have this problem.

Comment: I switched them around and everything worked out. Thanks man.